# Numeric sort in JSON

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I would like to sort a `JSON` field by the numeric value. Here is an example:

```
with tbl as (
  select json '1' j union all
  select json '2' j union all
  select json '"hello"' union all
  select json '"alpha"' union all
  select json '[1,2,3]'
) select j from tbl order by Float64(j)
```

However, this gives me an error saying (obviously):

> The provided JSON input is not a number; error in FLOAT64 expression

I know this of course, but the result I'd like to see is something more like the `TRY_CAST`, that is: treating all non-numeric values as `null`. What would be the proper way to do this? One option as I was writing this is to do a round-about `TO_JSON_STRING` cast and then apply the `TRY_CAST` on that. For example:

```
with tbl as (
  select json '1' j union all
  select json '2' j union all
  select json '"hello"' union all
  select json '"alpha"' union all
  select json '[1,2,3]'
) select SAFE_CAST(to_json_string(j) as float64) from tbl
```

Is that the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this as well.

```sql
with tbl as (
  select json '1' j union all
  select json '2' j union all
  select json '"hello"' union all
  select json '"alpha"' union all
  select json '[1,2,3]'
)
select SAFE.FLOAT64(j) from tbl;
```

- [SAFE. prefix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix)

**Query results**

[image]